# FLEX: ‘’ was not declared in this scope error

Tags: g++, flex-lexer

Im trying to compile a .l file using g++, but when i do, it brings up:

`‘LETTER’ was not declared in this scope`
and
`‘DIGIT’ was not declared in this scope`

```
%option noyywrap

%{
int mylineno = 0;
%}

%%

[ \t\n]   ;
[0-9]*    { return DIGIT;}
[a-zA-Z]* { return LETTER; }
.         { puts('Syntax Error'); }

%%

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int, char**) {
  
  // open a file handle to a particular file:
  FILE *myfile = fopen("/SOURCE/MAIN.mave", "r");
  // make sure it's valid:
  if (!myfile) {
    cout << "I can't open MAIN.mave!" << endl;
    return -1;
  }
  // set lex to read from it instead of defaulting to STDIN:
  yyin = myfile;
  
  // lex through the input:
  while(yylex());
}
```

This is strange, because it wasn't declared on purpose, because i don't have to declare it, at least that's what i think.

Comment: Well, yeah. They weren't. Where are those symbols defined? Are they from a bison file? In that case you need to include the haeder generated by bison. You add the include in the code section at the beginning marked by `%{` and `%}`, where the `mylineno` is defined.

Comment: No, because they're in the rules section, so that it would return 'DIGIT' or 'LETTER' to the bison file, right?

Comment: When you have a `return` statement in flex, all that it passes to bison is a single integer. Bison creates cosntants that assigns readable names to those integers but Flex doesn't know anything about that. For Flex it's just a piece of C code that it is supposed to paste into its output. You need to use normal C ways to make those contant from Bison defined in the code generated by Flex.

Comment: Oh! I think i know what you mean, I'll try that now.

Comment: How would i define it in bison?

Comment: Here is a decent explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666479/flex-bison-error-undeclared